# Firebase logout all accounts when user change password

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

How do I make that Firebase will logout from all accounts when the user is change its Password.

So if user have 2 devices that are connected to the same account, and one device change the password of the account, the other device will disconnect. The idea behind it is that if user's account is hacked, they can change their password and disconnected the hacker from their account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to logout and login regularly to check if the credentials save on the device are still valid. Depending on your security requirements you have to decide how often you do this. The most restrictive way would be before every Firebase call, the least restrictive would be when your app becomes active. I would:

- introduce a `last password check` `Date` entry in `UserDefaults`
- introduce a `timeout`constant (5 minutes)
- save `Date()` when logging in
- write a wrapper around calls, that compares the time interval in between `now` and `last password check` with `timeout`
- if `timeinterval` > `timeout`, re-login

Comment: This is not what I meant. What I am trying to do is that if user have 2 devices that are connected to the same account, and one device change the password of the account, the other device will disconnect. The idea behind it is that if user's account is hacked, they can change their password and disconnected the hacker from their account.

Comment: Ok, but why did you accepted the answer :-).

Comment: @GyuriMajercsik probably because he found out that's what the answer does (after writing the comment)